# Generated java source code not found by kotlin compiler

Tags: java, android, kotlin, code-generation, gradle-plugin

I'm writing a gradle plugin to generate Java code.  My plugin generates code that's based on the  Android R class, so it's dependent on the

```
processVariantResources
```

Task. In my plugin, I'm  using this code to do that:

```
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {
override fun apply(project: Project) {

    val extension = project.extensions.create<MyPluginExtension>(PLUGIN_NAME, MyPluginExtension::class.java)
    project.tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        if (task.name.startsWith("process") && task.name.contains("Resources") && !task.name.contains("Test")) {
            val index = task.name.indexOf("Resources")
            val variantName = task.name.substring(7, index)

            //Create my task and add it to the project, make it dependent on processResources
            project.task("my${variantName}ResourceTask") {
                it.doLast {
                    generateSomeCodeForVariant(project, extension, variantName)
                }
                taskList.add(it)
            }.dependsOn(task)
        }
    }

    project.afterEvaluate {
            val appExtension = project.extensions.findByType(AppExtension::class.java)
            appExtension?.applicationVariants?.all { variant ->
                val myTask = project.tasks.getByName("my${variant.name.capitalize()}ResourcesTask")
                    val outputDir = "${project.buildDir}/generated/source/myplugin/${variant.name}"

                    //register my task as java generating
                    variant.registerJavaGeneratingTask(myTask, File(outputDir))
            }
    }
}
```

then, in the build.gradle of the project where I'm using this plugin, I've added

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs += ['build/generated/source/myplugin']
            kotlin.srcDirs += ['build/generated/source/myplugin']
        }
    }
}
```

My plugin actually generates source code to the directory:

```
build/generated/source/myplugin/com/mygroup/myartifact
```

Anyway, the code gets generated correctly, and put in the correct place, but I can't get the compiler to recognize my generated code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I refactored the code and implemented the strategy describe here:

my new code looks like this:

```
project.afterEvaluate {
        val appExtension = project.extensions.findByType(AppExtension::class.java)
        appExtension?.applicationVariants?.all { variant ->

            val processResourcesTask = project.tasks.getByName("process${variant.name.capitalize()}Resources")
            val myTask = it.task("my${variant.name.capitalize()}ResourceTask") {
                it.doLast {
                    doSomeStuff(project, extension, variant.name.capitalize())
                }
            }.dependsOn(processResourcesTask)

            val outputDir = "${project.buildDir}/generated/source/myplugin/${variant.name}"
            variant.registerJavaGeneratingTask(myTask, File(outputDir))
            val kotlinCompileTask = it.tasks.findByName("compile${variant.name.capitalize()}Kotlin") as? SourceTask
            if (kotlinCompileTask != null) {
                kotlinCompileTask.dependsOn(myTask)
                val srcSet = it.objects.sourceDirectorySet("myplugin", "myplugin").srcDir(outputDir)
                kotlinCompileTask.source(srcSet)
            }
        }
    }
```

I also removed the sourceSets definition from the client build.gradle file, and 
 now everything works correctly.